# Update only one element in one CardView (Android Recyclerview)

Tags: android, image, progress-bar, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Having read a lot of questions answering "how to update one single row of `ListView` or `RecyclerView` (which would be `notifyItemChanged(position)`), i have a more "nested" question:

My custom `RecyclerView` `ImageRecycler` holds a couple of `CardView`s. In these cardviews, we can find a `ProgressBar` and an `ImageView`.

Logic: I open a file chooser elsewhere, choose an image, starts displaying / fading it in for 2 seconds in the newly added `CardView`, while i am also uploading it to a server. So during my image animation, i want to be updated for the upload progress as well. For the last said, i use a `LocalBroadcastReciever` calling `notifyItemChanged(position)`.

To load the `ImageView`, i use `Glide` for asynchronous image loading in my adapter:

```
            File f = new File(entries.get(position).getFilePath());
            Glide
                    .with(main)
                    .load(f)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .crossFade(2000)
                    .into(holder.iv1);
```

Which leads to my problem:

Image is uploading, notify-method called a few times, which uploads the ProgressBar (yay!), but also makes Glide reloading the image again and again, so the screen starts flickering.

I already tried to animate the image only for the first time, after that, i only call my view holder to just set the already loaded image:

`holder.iv1.setImageBitmap(entries.get(position).getBitmap());`

But this makes the scrolling of my RecyclerView very faltering.

So how can i refresh only the ProgressBar as a part of CardView, but allowing the "old" image to stay?

Comment: can you post your progressbar update method please !

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?